# ng-repeat with key and value then use the key to be a directive value for ng-model

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

It is possible to have the key for a scope variable to be used in a ng-model directive?

What I wanted is not to manually put the keys for each ng-model directive, I just wanted to use the ng-repeat and get the key for a scope variable and put it on the ng-model inside the ng-repeat directive.

I'm just a newbie on this framework. Any help would be greatly appreciated

**Markup snippet**

```
<div ng-show="editing">
    <input ng-repeat="(key, value) in editing" ng-model="editing.key">
</div>
```

**HTML**

```
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <title>Demo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/app.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div classs="container" ng-controller="UserProfile">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="user in users"><a href="" ng-click="editProfile(user.id)">{{user.id}} - {{user.fname}} </a></li>
        </ul>
        <div ng-show="editing">
            <input ng-repeat="(key, value) in editing" ng-model="editing.key">
        </div>  
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
function UserProfile ($scope) {
  $scope.users = {
    "ID01": {
      "id": "ID01",
      "fname": "Vincent",
      "lname": "Panugaling",
      "gender": "male",
      "age": "21",
    },
    "ID02": {
      "id": "ID02",
      "fname": "Adrian",
      "lname": "Santos",
      "gender": "male",
      "age": "22"
    },
    "ID03": {
      "id": "ID03",
      "fname": "Incognito",
      "lname": "Mode",
      "gender": "female",
      "age": "21"
    }
  };

  $scope.editProfile = function (id) {
    $scope.editing = $scope.users[id];
  };
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `ng-model="editing[key]"`? Dynamic access for a dynamic value.

Comment: I tried the `ng-model="editing[key]"` but it only accepts 1 character per input and my cursor losts the focus on a input element, you can check my screen capture http://screencast.com/t/yUMBqgkxEm

btw thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Not sure where your focus issue is coming from, but this works: http://plnkr.co/edit/onk1FdM6WcdEvOp5XZdu?p=preview

Comment: I will try to figure out the focus issue, Thanks!

Comment: The problem is with angular version thanks for the help @Brocco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this view you are expecting please have a look, yes it is possible to use key as ng-model.
Hey dude you are using angular 1.0.1 version thats why you can edit once and focus is getting out use latest version check out the same demo

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jzcy9fto/)

**html code**

```
<div classs="container" ng-app="app" ng-controller="UserProfile">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="user in users"><a href="" ng-click="editProfile(user.id)">{{user.id}} - {{user.fname}} </a></li>
        </ul>
        <div ng-show="editing">
            <input ng-repeat="(key, value) in editing" ng-model="editing[key]">
        </div>  
    </div>
```

**angular.js**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

function UserProfile ($scope) {
  $scope.users = {
    "ID01": {
      "id": "ID01",
      "fname": "Vincent",
      "lname": "Panugaling",
      "gender": "male",
      "age": "21",
    },
    "ID02": {
      "id": "ID02",
      "fname": "Adrian",
      "lname": "Santos",
      "gender": "male",
      "age": "22"
    },
    "ID03": {
      "id": "ID03",
      "fname": "Incognito",
      "lname": "Mode",
      "gender": "female",
      "age": "21"
    }
  };

  $scope.editProfile = function (id) {
    $scope.editing = $scope.users[id];
  };
}
```

Comment: I have added link sorry i dont knw how to provide link properly

Comment: You should still include your code in your answer so that if they link provided becomes unavailable your answer is still useful.

Comment: oh ok sorry sir I will include it now

Comment: No worries, [here is a nice reference for answering questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Thank you sir. I tried including fiddle link in my code but every time  i fail to provide that fiddle link in anchor tag(mean blue color).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59113/discussion-between-malkus-and-sudarshan).